# Highlight values based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, styles

I want to shade the values (cells) that **equal or exceed** the guideline values (currently in a dictionary, key (chemical symbol):value (guideline limit).  I want it to deal with multiple sets of guidelines and shades the cell according to the guideline with the highest value that is being exceeded. The table below shows the desired output, with the guidelines assigned a color, and the exceedances of each guide assigned the same colour.

[image]

This shows the limits for three different guidelines (ANZECC, WHO, and US EPA) for Cu, Cd, SO4 and Zn. The results are below (site 1 -3) and are highlighted according to which (if any) guidelines they exceed. So for the first parameter, Cu,  site 2 only exceeds the US EPA value so is shaded yellow. Site 1 all the guidelines the highest is the WHO value so is shaded blue. Site 3 also exceeds all the guidelines, the maximum is WHO, so is shaded blue as well. Cd for site 1 exceeds US EPA and ANZECC (which are the same) so is shaded green (but could have been shaded yellos as the US EPA limit is the same). Site 2 doesn't exceed any of the guidelines so is left unshaded. Site 3 exceeds all the guidelines, the highest for Cd is WHO, so is shaded blue. and so on.

I can shade exceedances against one guideline using the code below,

```py
#example dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(({'Cu':[0.004, 0.0017, 0.1],  'Cd': ['0.001','0.0005',1], 'SO4': [700,"450",1500],'Zn': ['0.15','0.1','0.25'],}))
cols=df.columns
```

Gives

```
Out[7]:
      Cd      Cu   SO4    Zn
0   0.001  0.0040   700  0.15
1  0.0005  0.0017   450   0.1
2       1  0.1000  1500  0.25

#guideline values
WHO=  {'Cd' :0.002 ,'Cu' :0.003 ,'SO4':"NaN",'Zn' :0.1}
ANZECC=  {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.002 ,'SO4':1000.0,'Zn' :0.2}
US_EPA=  {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.0015 ,'SO4':500.0,'Zn' :0.01}

#highlight the relevant cells that are greater than the guideline
def fill_exceedances(x):
    color = 'orange'
    #get columns which are in keys of dict
    c = x.columns.intersection(ANZECC.keys())
    #filter columns and rename by dict
    df2 = x[c].rename(columns=ANZECC)
    #create boolean mask only for matched columns and compare
    mask = df2.astype(float).values < df2.columns[None,:].values
    #new DataFrame filled by no color
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=c)
    #set color by mask and add missing non matched columns names by reindex
    df1 = (df1.where(mask, 'background-color: {}'.format(color))
              .reindex(columns=x.columns, fill_value=''))

    return df1

df.style.apply(fill_exceedances, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

This gives, for the ANZECC guidelines:

[image]

I can't figure out how to apply successive styles as the previous styles are lost if I repeat the process. I feel I am approaching this the wrong way and successive styling from the minimum guideline upwards wont work.

UPDATE: I have put the guidelines into one dictionary, and can sort them and assign a colour based on the guideline in use, but I am stuck with how to proceed.

```py
guidelines={"CEPA_FW":  {'Sulphate':1000,'Cd' :0.01 ,'Cu' :1.0 ,'Pb' :0.005 ,'Zn' :5.0}, 
 "ANZECC_Stock":{'Sulphate':1000,'Cd' :0.01,'Cu' :0.4, 'Zn' :20},
 "ANZECC_FW":  {'Sulphate':1000,'Cd' :0.0002 ,'Cu' :0.0014 ,'Pb' :0.0034 ,'Zn' :0.008}}


df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(guidelines).T
df
```

Gives:

```py
Out[3]:
                  Cd      Cu      Pb  Sulphate      Zn
ANZECC_FW     0.0002  0.0014  0.0034    1000.0   0.008
ANZECC_Stock  0.0100  0.4000     NaN    1000.0  20.000
CEPA_FW       0.0100  1.0000  0.0050    1000.0   5.000
```

Then sort the guidelines and assign colour, with:

```py
fill_color={'ANZECC_FW':'blue',
'CEPA_FW' :'green',
'ANZECC_Stock': 'yellow'}

for i in df.columns:
    col=df[i]
    col=col.sort_values(ascending=True)
    #print col,i, col.idxmax()
    #print i
    #print col
    count=0
    for val in col:

        if val>0:

            print i,val,col.index[count],fill_color[col.index[count]]

            count+=1
        else:
            continue
```

Gives:

```py
Cd 0.0002 ANZECC_FW blue
Cd 0.01 ANZECC_Stock yellow
Cd 0.01 CEPA_FW green
Cu 0.0014 ANZECC_FW blue
Cu 0.4 ANZECC_Stock yellow
Cu 1.0 CEPA_FW green
Pb 0.0034 ANZECC_FW blue
Pb 0.005 CEPA_FW green
Sulphate 1000.0 ANZECC_FW blue
Sulphate 1000.0 ANZECC_Stock yellow
Sulphate 1000.0 CEPA_FW green
Zn 0.008 ANZECC_FW blue
Zn 5.0 CEPA_FW green
Zn 20.0 ANZECC_Stock yellow
```

So I have all the info, I just need to loop through these in order for each column in the data (if cell value >= list value, assign the fill color) which should work, but I am stuck with how to apply this.

Comment: What is format of limits? It is another DataFrame? Or list of dictionaries?

Comment: Is possible edit question with this format like picture data?

Comment: @jezrael Is that better? Yes limits are dictionaries.

Comment: sorry, busy, but working for it.

Comment: What happen if match 2 values? Then what value is prioritize?

Comment: no preference for the same value, can be either guideline.

Comment: @jezrael updated with my latest efforts and fixed inconsistencies.

Comment: bounty added to hopefully entice some answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, few problems in your question:

1. Your data are **not** consistent: The code provided to generate `df` contains some strings mixed with floats. If this really is the case in your data, the first thing you should do is converting all to float:

   df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
2. Your `guidelines` change throughout the post. For example:

You started with guidelines as

```
WHO=  {'Cd' :0.002 ,'Cu' :0.003 ,'SO4':"NaN,'Zn' :0.1}       # string `NaN` again?
ANZECC=  {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.002 ,'SO4':1000.0,'Zn' :0.2}
US_EPA=  {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.0015 ,'SO4':500.0,'Zn' :0.01}
```

Then, later on you build your `guidelines` dataframe, which you must have mistakenly named `df` as well, as:

```
# no string `NaN`
# Sulphate or SO4
# different standard names
guidelines={"CEPA_FW":  {'Sulphate':1000,'Cd' :0.01 ,'Cu' :1.0 ,'Pb' :0.005 ,'Zn' :5.0}, 
 "ANZECC_Stock":{'Sulphate':1000,'Cd' :0.01,'Cu' :0.4, 'Zn' :20},
 "ANZECC_FW":  {'Sulphate':1000,'Cd' :0.0002 ,'Cu' :0.0014 ,'Pb' :0.0034 ,'Zn' :0.008}}
```

This is totally different from the former.

---

That said, let's build a new `guidelines` and `fill_color` based on your picture:

```
guidelines = {'WHO' :  {'Cd' :0.002 ,'Cu' :0.003 ,'SO4':np.NaN,'Zn' :0.1},
              'ANZECC' : {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.002 ,'SO4':1000.0,'Zn' :0.2},
              'US_EPA' :  {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.0015 ,'SO4':500.0,'Zn' :0.01}
              }
guidelines = pd.DataFrame(guidelines).T

fill_color = {'WHO':'teal',
              'US_EPA' :'yellow',
              'ANZECC': 'green'}
```

And here comes the function:

```
def hightlight(col):
    name = col.name

    # extract the threshold and sort decreasingly
    thresh = guidelines[name].sort_values(ascending=False)

    # compare each value in column to each threshold
    compare = np.greater_equal.outer(col.values, thresh.values)

    # if any threshold is exceeded
    exceed_thresh = compare.any(1)

    # and where it is exceeded
    exceed_idx = np.argmax(compare, axis=1)

    # extract the standards that has is passed
    standards = np.where(exceed_thresh, thresh.index[exceed_idx], '')

    # format strings
    return [f'background-color:{fill_color[s]}' if s else '' for s in standards ]

df.style.apply(hightlight)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did specify that the data may contain Nans or blanks in the note relating to the bounty. Thanks for pointing out the inconsistencies, i will fix. Your code returns an error: NameError: ("name 'c' is not defined"...

Comment: sorry, missed refactor, `c` should be replaced by `s` at `return` line. Fixed.

Comment: Would it be simple to make this work if the input data has columns not in the guidelines?

Comment: Yes, just check `if name not in guidelines.columns: return ['']*len(col)` right after defining `name` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is how you can go about it:

**Edit:**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
data=pd.DataFrame(({'Cd': [0.001,0.0005,1],'Cu':[0.004, 0.0017, 0.1],  'SO4': [700,450,1500],'Zn': [0.15,0.1,0.25],}))

guidelines = {'WHO' :  {'Cd' :0.002 ,'Cu' :0.003 ,'SO4':np.NaN,'Zn' :0.1},
              'ANZECC' : {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.002 ,'SO4':1000.0,'Zn' :0.2},
              'US_EPA' :  {'Cd' :0.001 ,'Cu' :0.0015 ,'SO4':500.0,'Zn' :0.01}
              }
guidelines = pd.DataFrame(guidelines).T

fill_color = {'WHO':'teal','ANZECC': 'red','US_EPA' :'yellow'}

def highlight(x):
  if x.name in guidelines.columns:
    style = []
    guide = guidelines[x.name]
    for i in x:
      condition = (guide<=i)
      _guide = guide[condition]
      try:
        match = _guide.index[np.argmax(np.array(_guide))]
        color = fill_color[match]
        style += [f"background-color: {color}"]
      except:
        style += ['']
    return style
  else:
    return ['']*len(x)

data.style.apply(highlight)
```

Looks like this (you can go on and add further formatting / change the colours etc.):
[image: pandas styling]

Comment: Thanks, this creates a new dictionary 'greater_than_condition' and compares every column against this, but there is a guideline for each column, as defined by the 'guidelines' dictionary. There is no need for 'greater_than_condition' library.  Your answer has also shaded the guidelines, not the data (1st code box in question).  Looks like your approach could work if the correct dictionaries are referenced.

Comment: Yeah, I think i mistakenly assumed guidelines as your data, so, I added another `dict` to show how you can add conditions. Let me add the df in the code and use guidelines for coloring instead!

Comment: Thanks, can you check this, I get no styled output when I run your code.

Comment: Aha! Did you get an error for `np.argmax` (that didn't show up on colab)? Now, fixed.